# Angular-mocks digest doesn't wait for promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-mock

I want to have to function that returns a promise that resolves when the DOM is loaded:

```
function waitForDom() {
  return $q((resolve) => {
    $window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      resolve("yay, i've loaded");
    });
  })
})
```

This works just fine running in the browser. However, when I try to test it, the test never finishes as this promise never resolves:

```
it('some test', (done) => inject(($window, $q, $rootScope) => {
  waitForDom()
    .then(it => expect(it).toBe("yay, i've loaded"))
    .then(done);

  $rootScope.$digest();
}));
```

From what I understand of angular, promises don't resolve (and chain) until you call `$digest`. This makes it so that you can test angular in a synchronous fashion. I get it. However, the example that I have here *should* finish, but for some reason it always times out.

I've tried putting the `resolve()` inside `$scope.$apply()`, but I get "$digest already in progress".

I've tried putting the `$digest` inside `setTimeout` and that gives me a $digest already in progress too, which I'm *really* confused about. But that's not really the problem.

**TLDR** How do I get my test to actually finish?

**Edit**

While I can work around my above example, I'm looking for a general solution for when you resolve a promise inside the body of a DOM event listener, like this:

```
function appendIframe() {
  return $q((resolve) => {
    const iframe = $window.document.createElement('iframe');
    const iframeParent = $window.document.body;

    iframe.src = authUrl;

    iframe.onload = function() {
      resolve('iframe loaded')
    };

    iframeParent.appendChild(iframe);
  });
})
```

And no, doing this with jqlite doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the `DOMContentLoaded` event is actually firing when you run your test?

Comment: Yup. When I log inside the event callback, it always eventually gets printed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

```
function waitForDom() {
  return $q((resolve) => {
    angular.element( () => {
      resolve("yay, i've loaded");
    });
  })
})
```

From the Docs:

> Most browsers provide similar functionality in the form of a `DOMContentLoaded` event. However, jQuery's .ready() method differs in an important and useful way: If the DOM becomes ready and the browser fires `DOMContentLoaded` before the code calls .ready( handler ), the function handler will still be executed. In contrast, **a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener added after the event fires is never executed.**

Comment: I ended up doing as much to fix this part. However it doesn't quite get at the core issue I'm having. This works around promises and events, but I have another event later on in the chain that resolves in the `onLoad` event of an iframe. I can't use this workaround there.